# Find all records who has exactly 3 associated records in another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a the following models

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  ...

class AdvancedPriceLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price
  ....
```

I want to find all `Price` records which have exactly 3 `LineItem` referencing it

How can this be done?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way for active record

```
Price.includes(:line_items).group("line_items.price_id").having("count(*) = 3")
```

Comment: This throws the following error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "line_items"`

Comment: yes you need to used proper association name and table name in query i was just used this name according to you model. otherwise put you model and schema here

Comment: Updated the post with associations and names

Comment: @Tarlen this query is correct according to association name and its working in `mysql` as per your error i think if your table name is `advanced_price_line_items` then replace group with `group("advanced_price_line_items.price_id")` it depend on you table name

Comment: No they should be correct. I can call `Price.last.line_items` and it works

Comment: @Tarlen it is correct but in group you need to put table name not association name. replace above group in query and check it is working or not??

Comment: The association name is the same as the table name

Answer (score 0):

here you go..

```
select * from
price where  id in (select price_id
from LineItem
group by  price_id
having count(*) =3
)
```

Comment: in case id from price table is equivalent to other column  in LineItem change accordingly in inner query

Comment: @anwar_hell is `group by id` works here?? i think in line item table `id` is uniq. you needs to used foreign_key for group not primary

Comment: @vishal.. if id is unique replace it with other say price_id

Comment: Remove ",count(id)" from the sub-query's select list. And do IN instead of = sub-query.

Comment: corrected the query but using = or in doesn't makes much difference as parser with generate same plan...

Comment: I get a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`

Comment: @Tarlen..correct my correct as per jarlh suggestion and i think it sould return correct result now.